# Elementary Linear Algebra with Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Is there any way to make this formulae simpler?

$(\alpha|1\rangle\otimes\beta|O1\rangle+\beta|2\rangle\otimes|O2\rangle)\otimes|1\rangle$

Comment: It's not clear how to interpret your notation. Note that the sum $|1 \rangle + (\alpha |1 \rangle \otimes \beta | O1 \rangle)$ is not well-defined since you are adding vectors from distinct vector spaces.

Comment: I see, thanks! I deleted the first formula. Then how about the remaining one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "simpler". One option is to "expand" the expression and move any constants to the front:
$$
(\alpha|1\rangle\otimes\beta|O1\rangle+\beta|2\rangle\otimes|O2\rangle)\otimes |1\rangle = \\
\alpha\beta (|1\rangle\otimes|O1\rangle \otimes | 1 \rangle) + \beta (|2\rangle\otimes|O2\rangle\otimes|1\rangle).
$$